# Android Countdown Timer in Broadcast receiver doesn't update TextView

Tags: java, android, multithreading, timer, android-activity

I am creating application which works with SMS service and **FTP** networking.

If user does not establish connectivity, it will try to reconnect again in 30 seconds.

I am using CountDownTimer with TextView to inform user about time left to reconnnect.

Either it will be successful or it will start counting again.

My problem is, that if counter restarts while activity is in background or the screen is locked, TextView keeps showing number **"1"** (it won't update) until the timer restarts again in foreground (but updating numbers without timer restart works fine in backround or lock, I am using wakelock in my foreground service).

After counter restarts again (so it won't stop counting) while application is in foreground, everything comes back to normal, TextView updates from freezed **"1" to "30"** and starts counting down to **"1"**.

I think problem will be somewhere in communication between counter thread and background activity with UI, but I don't know nothing more about it.

I tried several things like:

1. creating setter and getter for miliseconds and update them in each
   tick, then try to update textview from `onReume()`, didn't work.
2. create local variable for TextView inside timer, initialize it inside `onTick()` and
   try to update text from there, also didn't work.

Thanks everyone for help, I will appriciate any advices.

Part of code relative to question:

```
private CountDownTimer cdt = null;
private final TextView getTextView_ActivityMainMenu_Timer(){
  return (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ActivityMainMenu_TextView_Timer);
}

private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if(intent.getBooleanExtra("KEY_FAILED", false)){

      cdt = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {          
          getTextView_ActivityMainMenu_Timer().setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);                             
        }

        public void onFinish() {                        
          ;                     
        }

      }
      .start();

    }
    else
    {
      if(cdt != null)
        cdt.cancel();
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found solution of this problem. I didn't realize that I am unregistering the receiver in `onPause()` method. So I had to change it and put registration of broadcast into `onResume()` and unregister it only in `onDestroy()` method.

Comment: Thanks, saved me a few minutes scratching my head on this one!