# Starting countdown timer in background on receiving push notification

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I want to start a countdown timer when a push notification is received.

I can receive the notification successfully.

Now I want to ask, is it possible to start countdown timer in onReceive of BroadcastReceiver when a notification is received and my application is in background or foreground?

Simply, I should say that the timer should start whether the app is in foreground or not.
And when the timer is finished it should send some data to server.
And I need to show the remaining time in a text view as soon as app comes to foreground during the countdown.

I am adding some code, please help me out.

This is code to start the timer and this function is called in onReceive.

```
void startOrderCountDown() {
    CountDownTimer orderCountDown = new CountDownTimer(40000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Constant.remainingTimeOfOrder = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
            Log.v("Timer", "Time left: " + millisUntilFinished
                    / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    String dr_id = myPreferences.getDRIVERID();
                    String res = new ServerConnection()
                            .updateOrderMissedRejected(
                                    Constant.UPDATE_MISSED_REJECTED_ORDER,
                                    dr_id, "", "0");
                    Log.e("Timer", "finished..." + res);
                }
            }).start();
        }
    };
    orderCountDown.start();
}
```

But When the notification arrives, it just prints "Time left: 39" in logcat.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24056149/android-countdown-timer-in-broadcast-receiver-doesnt-update-textview

Comment: @MichaelShrestha I am also doing something like that as I have posted, but the problem is that the timer just calls onTick method once. and only one line is printed in the logcat.

Comment: try debugging your receiver class ...

Comment: you need to start a service with a timer that dose not get stopped from the OS

Comment: @SpyZip Isn't there anyway else to do this ?

Comment: @MichaelShrestha I've debugged it, goes into the function, also goes to orderCountDown.start(); ,,,,, but even then its not getting started and isn't throwing any exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for countdown timer.

Just follow the steps.

1) Create AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.java

```
public class AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements IjoomerSharedPreferences {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Call your sever task.
    }
}
```

2) set alarm from current time when you receive push notification.

```
long INTERVAL = 40000;
AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1010, intent, 0);

try{
    am.cancel(pi);
}catch (Exception e){
}
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + INTERVAL, pi);
```

2) Manifest.xml

```
<receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="com.XXX.ZZZZ.AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver"></receiver>
```

Comment: Thanks for response. Is it possible to get the time remaining in the alarm to end ?

Comment: For that you need some programming stuff. You just need to store the  time-stamp in shared preference when set the alarm and when you want to get the remaining time just read the time stamp from shared preference and get the difference of current time stamp and stored time stamp.

Comment: will this alram get cancelled automatically when broadcast is received ? Or do we have to explicitly cancel it in AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver class ?