# How to resume the timer in dialog box when app opens on clicking the notification

Tags: android, service, dialog, countdowntimer

I have a dialog box that starts when any push notification arrives and it is of 30 seconds. It is working fine if the app is in foreground but if the app is in background, the main activity starts and dialog box has to appear with the left over timer. But here, I am able to show dialog box but the time again starts from 30 seconds which I don't want.
What I have tried so far:
1. In FirebaseMessagingService, I have set a broadcastReceiver to send broadcast to other activities to start dialog. It is working fine and sending broadcast to start activities. and when I click on notification, dialog box appears but not showing timer.
2. I have tried to use service to start timer and the service is starting but timer is not working.
3. I have created another broadcastReceiver in first broadcast Receiver to set time in dialogBox. This is working even in background but not updating the timer values.
4. [Starting countdown timer in background on receiving push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26485024/starting-countdown-timer-in-background-on-receiving-push-notification) I have used this as well but in this how to update values.

```
if(event.equals(eventName)){
            String remoteMessageDate = remoteMessage.getData().get(eventName).toString();
            intent = new Intent(this, DashboardMapsActivity.class);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            booking = gson.fromJson(remoteMessageDate, BookingResult.class);
            sendAllocateBroadcast(AppConstants.INSTANCE.getRIDE_REQUEST(), booking);
            intent.putExtra(AppConstants.INSTANCE.getRIDE_REQUEST(),booking);
            Log.w(TAG, "setActions: "+ Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toLocaleString());
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
         //   intent.setFlags(Intent.FL);
            String message = "You have new booking";
            createNotification(message);
```

2. BroadcastReceiver

```
 BroadcastReceiver rideRequestreceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(intent.hasExtra(AppConstants.INSTANCE.getRIDE_REQUEST()))
            {
                Toast.makeText(DashboardMapsActivity.this,"booking Received",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                booking = (BookingResult) intent.getSerializableExtra(AppConstants.INSTANCE.getRIDE_REQUEST());
                countDownTimer(booking.getBooking().getBookingId());

                setFCMNewRideDialogValue(booking);
            }
        }
    };
```

3. CountDownTimer

```
 private void countDownTimer(final Integer bookingId) {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, TimerService.class);
        startService(intent1);
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000,1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
              //  Log.w(TAG, "onTick: "+ TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished));
                rideRequestDialog.setTimerValues(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
              //  Log.w(TAG, "onFinish: timer finish " );
                rideRequestDialog.rideDismiss();
                rejectRide(bookingId);
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

4. OnCreate

```
 if (intent.hasExtra(AppConstants.INSTANCE.getRIDE_REQUEST())) {
            booking = (BookingResult) intent.getSerializableExtra(AppConstants.INSTANCE.getRIDE_REQUEST());
            if(!(rideRequestDialog.dialogShowing()))
            {
                setFCMNewRideDialogValue(booking);
            }
        } else {
            // Do something else
        }
```

I want to show the dialog box with working timer values

Comment: you can easily create a custom timer and do what you want with handler threads

Comment: HMU if you still need some help i'll post some examples

Comment: @Mr.Patel How to create custom timer? Can you help me with that

Comment: Right now i'm very busy i'll post a solution later on

Comment: Looking forward to solution and Thanks @Mr.Patel